# $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] seemingly not available on PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php

I've run into a problem on a server running php 5.1.6 - the code i use to detect ajax requests isn't working as the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] variable is missing from the $_SERVER array. The same code works fine on php 5.2 and in firebug i can see the headers include X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest. Anyone know any more about this issue and how I can get round it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything else different? E.g. webserver software and/or version, PHP as module or cgi, security settings, additional modules?

Comment: the server giving me problems is running Plesk on Linux, with php 5.1.6 as an apache module (apache 2.2). Locally everything works fine, that set up is php 5.2.1 (as module) and apache 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Since php is installed as an apache module you can use [apache_request_headers()](http://docs.php.net/function.apache-request-headers) for debugging purposes.
Does the header show up in `debuglog.txt` when you add

```
function dbgLogRequest() {
  $s = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n request headers";
  foreach( apache_request_headers() as $name=>$value ) {
    $s .= "\n  $name: $value";
  }
  $s .= "\n____\n\n";

  file_put_contents('debuglog.txt', $s, FILE_APPEND);
}

dbgLogRequest();
```

to your code?

Comment: Thanks for this VolkerK - useful to know for any future issues I have. Managed to get this issue fixed - the site where i was experiencing the issue was a preview version of the site via Plesk. I moved the site to a dedicated domain and the issue disappeared. very strange

Answer (score 2):

The only things I can dig up are:

- IE browser may not be sending the header
- If you have a redirect then the header does not get forwarded
- Inline frames for file uploading don't use ajax so don't send this header

Thats all... Not much else out there...

Answer (score 0):

You are having some kind of a redirect either in your files or in your .htaccess that clears this header.

Comment: I can't see where this might be happening - I've emptied my .htaccess file and have tested for the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] variable in the constructor of the controller being requested and it isn't there. Very strange...